# A Question About HTTPS Certificates & Their Fingerprints

Tags: tls-intercept

Lately, I have been verifying the HTTPS cert fingerprints of the sites that I log in to, by using the fingerprint tool on grc.com to fetch the correct ones from them and then comparing those to the fingerprints I actually receive from these sites, but is it necessary for me to further check that the fingerprints I receive have remained the same, as I navigate from page to page on them?

In other words, is it possible for me to connect to a website using the correct certificate, but then be issued an incorrect one later, while I browse the site? Or is one check after I connect to the site enough?

Comment: Is there any particular reason you don't trust the certificate validation built into your browser?

Comment: Hi jwodder, I asked because we cannot fully trust cert validation in browsers, since it is possible to be MITMed with a fraudulent cert yet be presented with a normal-looking website. For example, you could visit your bank's website and it may look familiar, but if your connection is being intercepted by a MITM, then your connection to the site is not private, even though the site was served using HTTPS: Verifying the fingerprint of the site's cert will reveal if such is the case

Comment: That's not how HTTPS works.  An attacker can't pull off a MitM without either (a) the user ignoring and clicking through a browser warning, or (b) the browser's CA list already having been compromised.  What exactly makes you think "it is possible to be MITMed with a fraudulent cert yet be presented with a normal-looking website"?

Comment: I have read about attacks such as DNS spoofing and malicious Tor exit nodes that can result in my connection to a site being intercepted or me being redirected to a malicious version of a website, and I wish to take some steps to help me detect such attacks before I send data over a MITMed connection. I don't have deep knowledge on MITM attacks, so I will respectfully appreciate any advice you and any other forum members can give regarding them, and I hope that, if my question was too broad, I have clarified it to some degree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The certificate of a site can change any time (for example if it gets renewed) and thus the fingerprint will change too.

I don't know what kind of attack you fear but if you think that some hacker is able to man in the middle your connection to some HTTP site and will only do it sometimes then this hacker might be able to intercept the connection to grc.com too and change the fingerprints shown to you which means this looking at this site is not an effective way to detect such an attacker. But unless you have to do with a hacker which managed to hack a CA to get the certificates he wants and thus can do silent man in the middle attacks, the browser will warn you that something is wrong.

If you instead fear that your computer might be infected by some malware which installed new trusted root certificates for silent MITM attack then it is enough to check from time to time if the certificates have changed. Note that certificates also change in case of legal SSL interception which is done by many antivirus products and enterprise firewalls.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Steffen. What I wish to understand is if you consider it a good practice for me to compare a known fingerprint for a site to the one I receive from it, just prior to logging in to the site, to verify the its authenticity. Also, I wish to know if it would be redundant for me to continue to compare these fingerprints, as I browse from one page to another, on the site.

Comment: I use GRC because the site uses EV certificates, which -- and please correct me if I am wrong about this -- are very difficult or even impossible to spoof, and my browser (firefox or chrome) displays the name of the company that owns the site in the address bar, if I visit a site that uses EV certs. With respect, however, if there is a better means by which I can compare fingerprints, then please let me know.

Comment: @user311982: while it is not harder to spoof the certificate  for EV and others it is practically impossible to keep the EV property. Thus if you count on this your are probably more safe. As for doing all of this automatically have a look at [Perspectives Project](https://perspectives-project.org/).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Given what you have said, unless I have misunderstood your response, I may safely continue to use the GRC site for comparing certificates. However, because I wish to be certain of a site's identity, as I browse from one page on the site, to another, should I compare its certs each time I visit a new page on the site? Or is comparing the certs the first time I visit the site enough to verify that I am connected to the correct site and will remain so, as long as my connection to the site is held?

Comment: For example, if I compare certs before logging in to security.stackexchange.com, and verified that I am, indeed, connected to the right site, then will I need to, again, compare certs, if I decide to visit crypto.stackexchange.com? Or is doing this redundant? Also, thank you for the link on the Perspectives Project, I will check it out.

Comment: @user311982: As long is the certificate stays valid the browser will not notify you if the certificate changes, no matter if the change is due to a man in the middle or due to renewal or similar. Thus if you want to be sure you need to validate the certificate all the time and not only once.

Comment: Thanks again, Steffen, for your reply. Given what you have said, I will be sure to verify certs often when visiting important sites, and I will continue to use GRC as my means by which to do so. Have a good day.